# How do I tell bndtools resolution to not include "optionally required" bundles?

Tags: java, osgi, bnd, bndtools

In my app I use Felix SCR for service management. However, SCR imports two bundles (one transitively) one of which is `org.osgi.service.http` which starts a HTTP server which I don't need whenever run.

I want to remove both bundles from the finalised resolution. How do I do this? I assume it's a setting in the bnd file being resolved?

[image: Resolution result showing optional import]

Comment: Normally we don't include the optional bundles. Or at least we shouldn't. Could you give a bit more detail about the process you went through?

Comment: The process was: I clicked resolve :D Seriously, do you need the bnd files? Can I invoke the `debug` switch with bnd in the project to get more diagnostics?

Comment: Right. So the optional dependencies are shown in the optional tab and don't get pulled into the -runbundles unless you explicitly select them. Which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry - which optional tab are you referring to? I changed the screenie above to show the optional resources list, which is empty. This is a bndrun file btw, not a bnd file.

Comment: Ah. So there must be a bug, because the resource should not be included there if it only has optional dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait till 2.4.0, test, and file a bug if it doesn't work.